# presenting an expression as linear combination of squares

Tags: polynomials

Correction: For what values of the real number $a$, can
$$
a(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)+2(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)
$$
be expressed as sum of the form 
$$
\alpha x^2+\beta y^2+\gamma z^2
$$
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are real numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by "consider $a=0$" ? $a$ is a given number.

Comment: Ok. What about the rest values of  $a$'s ?

Comment: If the term can give negative values for some $x_i$, then the answer is no, otherwise yes.

Comment: Thanks. My question was incorrect. I rewrite it.

Comment: This is quite unclear. Are $x,y,z$ linear combinations of $x_1,x_2,x_3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For matrix,
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & a & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & a
\end{pmatrix}

Eigenvalues: $$a-1, \; a-1, \; a+2$$

Eigenvectors:

$$
v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \;
v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \;
v_{3}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Taking the orthonormal basis as: $\hat{v_1}, \hat{v_1}\times \hat{v_3}$ and $\hat{v_3}$

We have

> $$\textstyle
> \boldsymbol{x}^T
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   a & 1 & 1 \\
>   1 & a & 1 \\
>   1 & 1 & a
> \end{pmatrix}
> \boldsymbol{x}=
> \frac{a-1}{2}(x_3-x_1)^2+\frac{a-1}{6}(x_1-2x_2+x_3)^2+\frac{a+2}{3}(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2$$

May also refer to [**another answer**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775076/how-to-complete-the-square-with-3-terms/1775084#1775084).

Answer (score 0):

For $a=1$ we obtain $(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^2$, wheras for $a=0$ this is not a sum of three squares in general, because it can be negative, whereas the sum of three squares cannot be negative.

New question: yes, every real number is the linear combination of three squares.
So we always can represent $f_a(x_1,x_2,x_3)=a(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)+2(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)$ in the form $\alpha x^2+\beta y^2+\gamma z^2$, for all real $a$.